# How to Install Ubuntu on a Lenovo MIIX 300-10IBY

Tags: boot, uefi, lenovo, 32-bit, intel-atom

I own a Lenovo MIIX 300-10IBY 2in1 laptop. It came with windows 10 that nowadays barely works. I decided on installing some distribution of Linux, maybe ubuntu or lubuntu. The problem is that despite its 64bit Intel Atom chip it is equipped with a 32bit UEFI. With a bootia32.efi file, the USB stick boots fine and the installation of the system completes but after reboot the freshly installed system doesn't boot. I tried many tutorials on the internet and already asked on a few forums but didn't succeed in fixing this mess. I am open to any suggestions and commands to try, maybe someone here has already dealt with this type of thing?

Comment: you will need a 32-bit Grub, which your UEFI can read and can boot a 64-bit OS. I found this guide here https://medium.com/@realzedgoat/a-sorta-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-linux-on-32-bit-uefi-machines-d39b1d1961ec

Comment: Did you try this guide? [Install Linux on Lenovo Miix (Guide 2022)](https://super-useful-things.com/2021/05/02/install-linux-on-lenovo-miix/)